# can i configure linux jboss with iis without using apache and tomcat?If Yes then how?

Tags: linux, jboss, iis-8

My Jboss is deployed on `linux RHEL` and the  website currently is hosted through apache on Windows Server.

Now i don't want apache to host my website, I want it to be hosted through `Windows IIS services`.

Comment: http://www.myconnectionserver.com/support/tutorials/v90/iisProxy/index.html

Comment: i m not searching for this